# Establishing LDAP Connection with User not listed in Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, azure-active-directory, ldapconnection

I have an IP, username, and password that I use to connect to Active Directory via Active Directory Explorer. I'm attempting to establish a connection via Java using these credentials. However, the account that I log in to the server with is not listed in AD.

```
IP="1.1.1.20"
Username="Bob"
Password="password123"
```

To further complicate things, the base dn of the active directory im connecting to on 1.1.1.20 is different from the base dn included in the full dn of the user.

the base dn of 1.1.1.20 is dc=test,dc=this,dc=com, whereas the DN of the account I'm using to log in is

```
CN=Bob,OU=People,OU=Something,OU=Blah,DC=Fake,DC=Data,DC=local,DC=com
```

I have tried every combination I can think of of username & DN using the code snippet below to establish a connection.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
                env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://1.1.1.20:389");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=Bob,OU=People,OU=Something,OU=Blah,DC=Fake,DC=Data,DC=local,DC=com");
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password123");
                DirContext ctx = null;
                try{
                    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

I am able to establish an anonymous connection when I comment out the lines for SECURITY_PRINCIPAL and SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, but I cannot create a connection when using the username and password provided to me for Active Directory Explorer.

I know that the username and password are correct because I can log in with them using Active Directory explorer, so I'm assuming the issue is arising when I am combining the username and baseDN to create the principal.

Is it even possible, or would the account I'm using to log in need to be found on the same server I am viewing?

Comment: Are the AD Domains (DC=local,DC=com and dc=this,dc=com) in the same AD forrest?

Comment: The account could just be on a different domain, in the same forest or not.

Comment: @GabrielLuci If that is the case how should I proceed? I can't tell if they are in the same forest or not, but ideally I would use the Bob account to establish a connection

Comment: @jwilleke I'm not sure how I can check this with AD Explorer, and I'm running into issues with PowerShell tutorials as neither AD Domain is local. If they were in the same forest, would it be something like concatenating the DNs to form my principal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you know the full DN of the account you're using, so that should work.

I suspect that simple authentication is disabled on the domain, or isn't allowed because the account is on a different domain than you're connecting to.

So it might be as easy as changing the authentication method to Kerberos. Try replacing the line that sets `Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION` with this:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51314937/1202807) for more details.

*Update:* If that doesn't work, then you can use AD Explorer to check the supported authentication mechanisms.

1. Right-click the root of the domain, and click 'Properties'.
2. Click the 'RootDSE Attributes' tab.
3. Look for the "supportedSASLMechanisms" attribute (probably the last in the list).

Try each of the values in that attribute and see if any of them work.

Comment: Okay I've changed it, and I think it connected one time and has not worked again. To clarify, my credentials are...
CN=Bob,OU=People,OU=Something,OU=Blah,DC=Fake,DC=Data,DC=local,DC=com,

password123, &

ldap://1.1.1.20:389

. Do I need the "389" at the end since that is a simple port? Should my url have a reference to the other domain?

Comment: As long as that DN and password is correct, then it should work. My guess is that you just have to find the right authentication mechanism that works.

Comment: Port 389 is the default LDAP port, so it doesn't matter if you specify the port or not. Your URL should reference the domain you want to read from, whichever that is.

Comment: Is the computer you are running this from joined to one of those domains (any trusted domain)? If not, then Kerberos might not work. You might be able to try LDAPS (port 636), but that might get a little more complicated (for one, you will have to use the domain name, not the IP).

Comment: Before you try LDAPS, I updated my answer with how you can find which authentication mechanisms are supported.

Comment: There are 4 supported mechanisms it seems, GSSAPI is one of them. The computer I am running from is not joined to one of the domains. The IP I was given is a tunnel on my network that connects to theirs. I'm going to try each of the 4 mechanisms and report back

Comment: Ok, that makes sense that Kerberos (GSSAPI) doesn't work then. Hopefully one of the other methods will work.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I'm not really sure to be honest. Just try them all :)

Comment: I tried "env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 GSS-SPNEGO GSSAPI");" with no luck. According to the forum I saw, I should be able to list them like so and it tries each type in succession

Comment: The exception being caught is a "Invalid Authentication method" exception

Comment: Maybe just try one at a time then?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Internet was down so I tried to take a shortcut when building offline :/

Comment: GSSAPI gives a "GSS initiate failure" exception, whereas the other 3 result in ldap error 49 I believe, which may be invalid credentials. Not sure what I am doing wrong since I'm using the full DN and password I use to log in to AD Explorer. At a loss. Yep, code 52e, invalid credentials. I

Comment: The issue has to be with the Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL then  
  
I'm using the fully qualified DN provided to me as the principal

Comment: The plot thickens if you're interested. I obtained another IP, and I'm able to establish a "simple" security_auth LdapContext with the Full User DN and Password on this one. When I look at the new IP in AD Explorer, it has a different Base DN from 1.1.1.20. Despite this, I'm able to view both in AD Explorerer, yet only establish an LdapContext with the new one. I've tried every security_auth type, I've also tried switching to ldaps://1.1.1.20:636 and no luck. What would prevent me from establishing a context on one but not the other with the same credentials? @Gabriel Luci

Comment: If it has a different base DN, then it sounds like it's a totally different domain. So it makes sense that one might accept those credentials and the other doesn't.

Comment: To connect by LDAP over SSL (aka LDAPS) on port 636, you have to connect using the domain name that the SSL certificate is issued to. You cannot connect by IP.

Comment: At this point it may be easier to reach out and ask for a new account to be made on the 1.1.1.20 server. Thank you for your help!